# React Leaflet: Failed to load sourcemap

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

My leaflet map is failing to show even though I apparently set up all following documentation. The only message in console I get is:

- DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/injectGlobalHook.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

My component as per documentation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

const MapContent = props => {
  return (
    <Grid component="section" className="tkr-map__content leaflet-container" height="100vh" width="100%" item={true} sm={12} md={10}>
      <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default MapContent;
```

I'm not sure if at this point, it can depends from my local server, Material UI, webpack or something else I'm currently ignoring.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Import `leaflet.css` if you haven't done already and set `style={{height: '100vh'}}` on `MapContainer` not Grid. I think the error is irrelevant with the fact that map is not showing.

Comment: add sample code in codesandbox for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following steps should be followed 
install `yarn add leaflet react-leaflet`
add `css file` to `index.js` like below 
`import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`
and add `height` is important .`height: "400px"`
sample code

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "400px" }}
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: Yes apologies, I will have sometime to test it this weekend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with the "React Developer Tools" Chrome extension - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64706427/7024301).

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't fixing my issue, but interesting anyways.