# Angular 12 Content and Map of this Source is not available (only size() is supported)

Tags: angular, webpack, source-maps

After upgrading my Angular version to the latest I have the error:

```
Content and Map of this Source is not available (only size() is supported)
```

Any helps would be appreciated cause there is not a lot of information about this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Content and Map of this Source is not available" error after upgrading to Webpack 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131297/content-and-map-of-this-source-is-not-available-error-after-upgrading-to-webpa)

Comment: The sort and sweet of it is that the .angular folder found in your project directory sometimes gets corrupted and the best way to fix it is to delete the folder entirely. Then run "npm install" to recreate a bug free version, and then run "ng serve"

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by installing the 'source-map-support' npm package like so:

```
npm install source-map-support
```

Check out [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support).

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's the best decision to include another dependency to a project when there is a simple/ easy solution that already exist.

Comment: @WhoIsCarlo What is the simple/easy solution tho?

Comment: The solution that other user posted was to delete the .angular folder found in the project directory. Run "npm install" and then run "ng serve". This is the link to that post https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598099/4576769

Comment: has no effect. still getting this error.