# Content and Map of this Source is not available (only size() is supported) Angular 13

Tags: angular, source-maps, npm-start

I have been working with angular project and have angular version is 13 and node is 16 versions.

When i use command `npm run start` its throwing an error(compilation error). Pasted the error below

```
Error: Content and Map of this Source is not available (only size() is supported)
    at SizeOnlySource._error (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SizeOnlySource.js:16:10)
    at SizeOnlySource.buffer (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SizeOnlySource.js:30:14)
    at _isSourceEqual (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\source.js:21:51)
    at isSourceEqual (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\source.js:43:17)
    at Compilation.emitAsset (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:4171:9)
    at C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:548:28
    at C:\Users\proj\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1129:17
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\proj\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have tried these solution.None of them are permanent solutions.

1. Remove .angular folder from project and run **npm install** followed by **npm run start** command
2. set **sourceMap** flag as **false**
3. Tried to install **sourceMap** using **npm install** command

**webpack version**

[image]

These solutions are get it from the other stackoverfolw similar questions.

Anyone know why this error comes.

Do we have a permanent solution for this issue.
Expecting a better solution

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598099/4576769

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598099/4576769). The short and sweet of it is that the `.angular` folder found in your project directory sometimes gets corrupted and the best way to fix it is to delete the folder entirely. Then run `npm install` to recreate a bug free version, and then run `ng serve` (or `npm run start` if that's what you're used to).

Comment: I hate this answer, but it works. Sounds like a package-lock.json equivalent. Very mysterious, confusing, and usually messes something up at some point. Instead of spending hours trying to figure out how to do it the right way, let's just delete it and start from scratch!

Comment: @mwilson I fully agree with you and I wish the Angular team would address this properly because it's known bug, but in the mean time this is all we have.

Comment: There was some mentioning of changing the app.module in Angular section of github but there are no details given. Nevertheless this current solution works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I have Angular 14.2.12 and fix was to delete ".angular" folder, founded in the root of the application.

Comment: If you don't know where this folder is (for me, was at repository\target\angular) use "npx ng cache clean"

Answer (score -1):

Delete .angular and .node_modules. Than run npm install, afater npm start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know that there is no need to delete the node_modules folder, that isn't where the issue lies. It's only in the .angular folder