# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for

Tags: javascript, html, css

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.60.0/resources/app.asar/static/underscore-umd.js.map:

that's an error in the system, i cannot fixe it
well you try to help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339968/error-message-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-for-chr)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.