# Stop passing of `drawer.css.map` as id prop into my page component (source map)

Tags: next.js

I have a weird issue that I think has to do with source maps. Every now and then, I can see in the Terminal that `drawer.css.map` gets passed as the value of the `id` prop into my `Page` server component, and into my `generateMetadata` function.

This is accompanied by the following warning in Chrome Dev Tools:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> http://localhost:3000/users/drawer.css.map: Unexpected token '<',
> "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

I do not believe that I am the one causing this. I am not sure if it is caused by Next.js, or by Chrome.

My page file (src/app/users/[id]/page.tsx):

```js
export async function generateMetadata(
    { params: { id } }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
    // ...
}

export default async function Page(
    { params: { id } }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using WP Joli? A similar issue was discussed in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/devtools-failed-to-load-source-map-9/

Comment: No, I'm using Next.js. Is WP Joli a WordPress plug-in, or is it a browser extension?

Comment: It's a WordPress plug-in, but this does lead me to think your problem is similar to the one described here:
I've got similar issues before. It's similar to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339968/error-message-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-for-chr
It's a chrome issue, and you can just disable source-maps to ignore it.